# How can I get datatable into Dictionary class?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

In a windows form application (c#) I've a DataTable. This solution has a class called "AddressStandarizationSolution". What I'm trying to do is load my dictionary from my DataTable that is in the main form.
How could I do that?

```
public class AddressStandardizationSolution
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> directionals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> streetName= new Dictionary<string, string>();

public AddressStandardizationSolution()
{
    var _with1 = directionals;
        _with1.Add("E", "E");
        _with1.Add("EAST", "E");
        _with1.Add("E-R", "EAST");
        _with1.Add("N", "N");
        _with1.Add("NO", "N");

    var _with2 = streetName;
        //This DataTable has 100.000 records
        _with1.Add(errorFromDataTable, rightFromDataTable);
}
}
```

I'm sorry. My DataTable fields are:

```
error              |  right
MNTGoMRY AVEnue    |  MONTGOMERY AVE
```

Comment: how does your `DataTable` looks like ? is it just two columns ? and are the values in `DataTable` column, to be used for Key,  are unique ?

Comment: Not sure you've provided enough information here. What should be the key of the dictionary and what should be the value? What are the datatable fields?

Comment: I'm sorry. My datatable has just two columns. Unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to do it. For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> resultDictionary = dataTable.Rows.OfType<System.Data.DataRow>()
    .Select( s => 
        new
        {
            Error = s["Error"] as string,
            Right = s["Right"] as string
        }
        ).ToDictionary( k => k.Error, v => v.Right );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative, although it can be combined with Mike Peterson's answer :)

```
table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Field<string>("Error"), x.Field<string>("Right")))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: For `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` you need > .NET 3.5: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx